# Memory efficient alternative to str.replace()

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I have a csv file with 200k rows and about 40 columns. Specific column contains special character '|' that i want to replace with '_'.
However while doing str.replace and then .append i encounter OOM error on my 16GB RAM, there must be a more efficient way.

My code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

archive_loc = ('pathname')
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(archive_loc,'sample.csv'))

category = data['category'].values
category = category.tolist()

for string in category:
     new_string = string.replace("|", "_")
     category.append(new_string)
```

Comment: You can follow what @Barmar has suggested. Although if you're having a memory error, I'd resort to partitioning your data with a library like [dask](http://dask.org).

Comment: For this task there is no need to read your entire huge file into memory. Don't create a dataframe at all. Write a preprocessor program using module `csv` that processes your file one line at a time and writes out a modified one. That will run in a tiny amount of memory and your only limit on filesize is available disk space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't convert to a list and loop, do the replacement directly in the dataframe.

```
data['category'] = data['category'].str.replace('|', '_', regex=False)
```